# Firebase analytics custom event shows zero users even though event count is non-zero

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I am logging some new custom events using Firebase Analytics in a React Native app. The events do show up in the Firebase events page after some delay, but the user count for these new events is "0", and I am trying to determine what the issue is. Other custom events that were already in place do show a user count, so it does seem that Firebase is correctly configured in the app.

Here is a screenshot of the event page for a new event:

[image: Firebase Analytics event page showing zero users]

And here is the debug view where I have confirmed the event comes through and that my user ID is set. I call `setUserId` before logging these events. You can see that the user_id property is set:

[image: Firebase Debug View]

I have been logging this event for several days in an app build that is not in debug mode. The app has been used by just a handful of users.

Another issue that might be related is that these new custom events do not show on the "Events" dashboard. I have to click into a different event and then type the event name in the filter at the top of the screen (as can be seen in the first screenshot) to find the event.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi did you find any more information on this topic

Comment: @ahmetakil Apologies, I should have updated this question back when it was top of mind. My memory isn't clear on this now, and I no longer have access to this project. I want to say it was a bug in Firebase and not with how we were tracking events. It might have resolved itself once more events were accumulated, but I don't remember for sure. I'm sorry this is not more helpful.